# Is there a default user created during Citus AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, citus

I have created a Citus DB cluster using the Cloud Formation template here:

[Multi-Machine AWS Citus Cloud Formation](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/installation/multi_machine_aws.html#manual-cloudformation-deployment)

I can login to the DB using CLI once I go to the host in PuTTy.  This does not require a username/pwd.  And, this runs successfully.

```
/usr/pgsql-9.6/bin/psql -h localhost -d postgres
select * from master_get_active_worker_nodes();
```

I set the Inbound rules for the 5432 port to 0.0.0.0/0 just to allow my remote connection to the DB.

Yet, now, when I try to connect using a JDBC URL from a remote host, I don't know what username/pwd to enter into the PostgreSQL JDBC URL.  Is there a default user/pwd to use?

Answer (score 0):

Default username is ec2-user and there is no default password. As you can see from the pg_hba.conf file, authentication method for the localhost is defined as "trust". You may check the details of authentication methods from [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). So, you need to let remote hosts to access the db by changing the pg_hba.conf file.